# SQL-запросы с REGEXP - оптимизация и альтернативы

Tags: регулярные-выражения, mariadb, like, mysql

Наличие индекса ситуацию не спасает. Запросы типа:

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '(foo|bar|baz|qux)';
```

выполняются, мягко скажем, неспешно. В моём случае на таблице в 60 тыс. записей (MySQL) реальный запрос с 14 альтернативами отрабатывался 16 секунд.

Аналогичный запрос но с LIKE и OR на той же базе отработан за 1,3 секунды.

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%foo%'
                           OR field LIKE '%bar%'
                           OR field LIKE '%baz%'
                           OR field LIKE '%qux%';
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что передо мной яркий пример того, что незачем использовать регулярки где не попадя? Соответственно, второй вопрос: какими критериями вы пользуетесь при выборе между запросами с REGEXP и LIKE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Правильно ли я понимаю, что передо мной яркий пример того, что незачем использовать регулярки где не попадя?
```

Видимо да.

```
Соответственно, второй вопрос: какими критериями вы пользуетесь при выборе между запросами с REGEXP и LIKE?
```

Лично я никогда не использую регулярки. Фильтр по regexp-у это полюбому fullscan.

Фильтр по like '%aaa%' не может использовать индексы. Зато фильтр по like 'aaa%' может. В PostgreSQL, кстати, есть индексы на основе триграм, который работают под like '%aaa%'. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgtrgm.html

В целом я думаю, что полнотекстовый поиск вас спасёт.

Вот тут хорошая презенташка
http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql